# Reinstate cloned object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I would like to store the initial state of the "this" (global) scope as shown in the pseudo code below :

```
<script>
var copiedObject = Object.create(this);
x="foo";
console.log(x); // foo
</script>
```

and reset it to this state later on using :

```
<script>
this = Object.create(copiedObject);
console.log(x); // undefined since it's a copy before x was assigned
</script>
```

Is this the correct way of cloning this and using that clone to replace the original later on ? I would like to do this instead of "refreshing" the page of my HTML5/JavaScript app and purge
newly added functions from AJAX.

Comment: this can not be assigned

Comment: No. And no. And no, that's impossible in general.

Comment: "*purge newly added functions from AJAX.*" - what? Maybe you should describe your [actual problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) in a new question and we could help you solve that.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply! i'll find another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code you have posted, you are making a shallow copy of the object. So all the Properties of `o1` are copied by reference to `o2`, if these are complex types (Objects). What means:

```
 var o1 = { a: { b: 1 } },
     o2 = Object.create(o1);

o1.a.b = 10;
console.log(o2.a.b) // 10
```

What you need to do is deep copy ([SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object)), but as you might see, this will lead you down a very deep rabbit hole.